# XForms data model can not be saved in XML file

Tags: xhtml, xforms, xsltforms

I have the following XForms code:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="./xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="yes"?>
<html
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
   xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
   <head>
      <title>XForms Submit Example</title>
      <xf:model id="MyModel">
                <xf:instance src="./Model.xml"/>
                <xf:bind id="FirstName" nodeset="/MyData/FirstName"/>
                <xf:submission id="save" method="put" action="./myData.xml" replace="none" />
                <xf:submission id="loadDoc" action="./myData.xml" replace="instance" method="get" />
      </xf:model>
   </head>
   <body>
                <xf:input ref="FirstName" incremental="true">
            <xf:label>Please enter your first name: </xf:label>
         </xf:input>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                Output First Name: <xf:output ref="FirstName" />

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <xf:submit submission="save">
         <xf:label>Save</xf:label>
                </xf:submit>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <xf:submit submission="loadDoc">
         <xf:label>Load</xf:label>
                </xf:submit>

   </body>
</html>
```

This form contains one textbox field and two buttons `save` and `load`, and also 1 dependency to the file `Model.xml` which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyData>
                <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                <Data2>Two</Data2>
                <Data3>Three</Data3>
</MyData>
```

The problem is: When I entering some data to text box, pressing save button, the model should be saved to `myData.xml`. This file exists on disk and it is not read only

In fact nothing happens, and file's data will not be updated (by the way Load button works fine).

What is the reason of this behaviour and how to fix this and save entered data to external file?

Answer (score 2):

Did you already try adding "file://" in the action attribute?

-Alain

Comment: I prefer to use relative path to avoid mistake in URI, like I can specify file:///d:/MyData.xml or file:/d:/MyData.xml etc. 

The specified file name is correct. And XForms know that file exists. In case if I specify something like MyData_.xml, I will receive the message “The system cannot locate the resource specified” in debug mode of XSLTForms plugin. It is quite strange that file should exist, and will not be created, isn’t it?

Comment: Writing a file is quite different from sending data to a web server: within a browser, a Java applet is required!
Are you writing an offline application?

Comment: OK, I'll look at this as soon as possible.

Comment: So, I now have a fix for Firefox but Chrome does not want to apply a local XSLT stylesheet and Internet Explorer native XmlHttpRequest doesn't allow local file to be read...
Is a Firefox-only fix OK for you???